# Linear de-acceleration during rolling

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, rotation

When a disc is pushed on a frictional surface, due to the torque provided by friction, it slowly starts rotating.

My doubt is, is the de-acceleration provided to the linear motion of the body equal to the tangential acceleration (radius times angular acceleration), or is it equal to friction/mass and why?

Comment: It’s not described clearly. The disc is laying flat. It is laying on a surface? You push on the disc on its edge.  If so, it moves some and rotates as it moves until friction makes it stop translating and stop rotating. But is that it?  Or is the center fixed and can only rotate?

Comment: The center is not fixed, the disc( or any body that can roll) is on a frictional surface. As you push the body, it gains a velocity, but due to the friction, a torque is applied which initiates the rotation of the body. With time, the linear velocity of the center of mass decreases and the angular velocity of rotation increases until a time comes when w(angular velocity)= v(linear velocity) / Radius. Now, the body starts a purely rolling motion, i.e , no slipping, the point of contact remains at rest with respect to the surface.

Comment: Ok i see. It should be called a cylinder in this case. A disc is very thin like a plate and usually laying on its side. But I do see. The answer given appears correct

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: No, the angular acceleration ($\alpha$) of rotation is not equal to the tangential acceleration ($a$) divided by radius, $R$. The friction $f_s = \mu_k N = \mu_k M g$.
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{f_s}{M} = \mu_k g;\\
\alpha &= \frac{\tau}{I} = \frac{f_s R}{\frac{1}{2}MR^2} =\frac{2\mu_k g}{R};\\
\alpha &= \frac{2 a}{R}; 
\end{align*}

[image]

The velocity as function of time (the velocity at the center):
$$
v(t) = v_0 - a t = v_0 - \mu_k g t.
$$

and the angular velocity
$$
\omega(t) = 0 + \alpha t = \frac{2 \mu_k g}{R} t
$$

Thus, the velocity of the point of contact:
$$
v_{contact} = v(t) - R \omega = v_0 - \mu_k g t - R \frac{2 \mu_k g}{R} t = v_0 - 3\mu_k g t
$$

At time $t = \frac{v_0}{3\mu_k\, g}$, the velocity at contact point has no relative motion to the ground, $v(t) = R \omega(t)$ at this moment. Therefore, the motion changed from slipping to rolling without slipping, and frictional force change from kinetic friction to static friction $f_s \le \mu_s Mg$ ($f_s = 0$ indeed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a further query, why not? The Tangential acceleration of the point of contact is the acceleration with which the body should move as it is the only point of contact?

Comment: I am not quite sure of your meaning, but added some explanation in the post, Hope that helps.

Comment: The “why not” is this, the object is sliding and there is a friction force and 1. it has linear momentum from the push and 2. It is immediately losing linear momentum from the friction and 3. It is immediately developing angular momentum from the friction. So it is moving and starting to rotate - both. Therefore at any instant the center is moving, the point of contact is sliding AND it is rotating. Until pure rolling starts. Think of it this way: one extreme is pure rolling, one extreme is pure frictionless sliding. Until the time mentioned in the answer, we are in between those two extremes

Comment: The angular rotation does not equal tangential divided by radius because the point of contact slides.

Comment: I added a picture aiming to clarify your question.